# Xpath text() function usage

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have some html file which contains following content:

```
<div>Chapter 1. <span>Contents of chapter N1.</span> </div>
<div>Chapter 2. <span>Contents of chapter N2.</span> </div>
```

I am trying to extract text contained inside these tags and use xpath '//text()' function:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(html),parser)
text = list(set( tree.xpath('//text()') ))
text = " ".join(text)
```

It works fine except i would like to change the order of extraction. Right now i get the following result:

> Contents of Chapter N1. Contents of Chapter N2. Chapter 2. Chapter 1.

But i would like to get result as:

> Chapter 1. Contents of Chapter 1. Chapter 2. Contents of Chapter 2.

Is there any better way of doing this except than recursively processing each tag from top of the document to the bottom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `string(/)` wouldn't give you the answer you want? It's not quite the same as what you have, in that for the document `<p><i>Hello</i>!</p>` it will give you `"Hello!"` rather than `"Hello !"`, but in most cases I would think that's what you want.

Comment: I haven't tested "string(/)" yet but i need to preserve correct word separation in my resulting text. As far as i understand your approach, I am going to have problems with that. So processing my example would return "Chapter 1.Contents of Chapter 1.Chapter 2.Contents of Chapter 2." That would be a problem.

Comment: It depends on your markup. If you use mixed content in the conventional way, then my approach is right and yours is wrong - you will be adding additional whitespace where it is not appropriate. On the other hand if you want to add whitespace wherever there is an element boundary, your approach is better.

Comment: Michael, i ended up using your approach. I only modified algorithm to replace <br> tags with a div containing space. Without that modification i would get "Helloworld!" from '<div>Hello<br>world!</div>' which is not what i expected. By the way, i had to use regex replace in the original html before lxml tree creation because i couldn't make lxml replace() function work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to use `set` to remove duplicates.

In python, elements in a `set` are unordered, that means that the order in which you get the elements from a set is implementation dependent, so you can't use this method of removing duplicates if you want to preserve the order.

```
text = " ".join(tree.xpath("//text()"))
```

Would produce the expected result in your case where there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. You are right although the question was about Xpath :)